# Mach-O Linker error при компиляции Unity проекта в XCode

Tags: unity3d, ios, xcode

Получаю вот такую ошибку при компиляции: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tAbBs5PjFMVXxWBl1qaESVG9xG7rx8fm/view?usp=sharing. Provising profile создан и стоит, в Unity поставил ill2cpp, ARM64 сменить нельзя (поле серое). Менять таргеты на armv7 пробовал. Получаю ту же самую ошибку, но в одной из строк arm64 меняется на armv7. XCode версии 11.
Я в iOS разбираюсь не очень, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выключить Bitcode в настройках проекта Xcode[image: введите сюда описание изображения]